# Jenkins AWS Credentials plugin does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, aws-credentials

I have faced issue with a Jenkins.

Some details:

I am using AWS Credentials 1.33 plugin

Role was created in AWS IAM. (Action : "sts:AssumeRole")

Policy was applied to that role. (Action : "ec2:Describe*")

Credentials storing in Jenkins
[image]

Stage definition from the pipeline:

```
        stage('Run aws command') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',credentialsId: "f0cf35b9-8967-40a2-b338-33da428fdc04", accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
                        container('aws-cli') {
                                sh('env')
                                sh('aws sts get-caller-identity')
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get following error in Jenkins:

```
[Pipeline] { (Run aws command)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@59f986be: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@49ac96d0: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1269)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:845)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:794)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1727)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1694)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1683)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:501)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AWSCredentialsImpl.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsImpl.java:161)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding.bind(AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding.java:124)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep$Execution2.doStart(BindingStep.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:77)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### AWS Credential Provider Chain

The error message tells you everything you need to know.  AWS supports a variety of ways for a client to provide authentication information.  AWS conceptualizes these different methods of providing information as a "chain" because each method has its own order of precedence.

From your screenshot it's evident that you are not even configuring the the AWS ACCESS_KEY and SECRET in your credential manager.  You are leaving them blank, and then trying to establish a variable to hold the (blank) value in your `withCredentials` step.

For proof you can attempt to print

```
print "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"
```

It will return nothing.

#### Solution

Add the access key and the secret key to the credential record you are referencing in your `withCredential` step.  You don't even need to get the retrieve the values.

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',credentialsId: "f0cf35b9-8967-40a2-b338-33da428fdc04"]]) {
   container('aws-cli') {
      sh('env')
      sh('aws sts get-caller-identity')
    }
}
```

Also you might need withCredentials inside container

Comment: Thank you Chris. It works now. But I get following error `+ aws --region=eu-north-1 ec2 describe-subnets --query Subnets[*].[CidrBlock,AvailableIpAddressCount]
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/"`

Comment: This problem was resolved as well. It was proxy issue. Thank you

Comment: Yes CIDR whitelist needed. Glad to help